# Blocking ips with .htaccess behind varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, varnish

I have the following issue. I have a normal apache/varnish installation on a server with 5 IPs and varnish sends each request to apache using the local IP (which i think is normal since in the backend I can get the referrer with php's $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].

I cannot use though the .htaccess file's blocks since apache gets only the local IP. Everything I `deny from` inside .htaccess is never applied. If i go to port :81 (apache's port), the block works normally.

What I need to do is find a way to either block the IP from varnish itself or send back to apache the original referrer ID and all this without restarting varnish (Of course, if this is not possible, I will have to do so...)

That specific IP I want to block, is getting very suspicious......

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should install mod_rpaf on your apache server. This will update the remote address with the last IP address from the X-Forwarded-For header. On debian based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-rpaf
```

then restart apache.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I'll try this in a non-production server first to experiment with it. It seems the appropriate solution but the stderr.net site is unreachable at this moment.

Comment: Is there an alternate download site except stderr.net? It seems to be down completely

Comment: Have you checked your distribution repos to see if there is a precompiled binary available for your distribution? The latest file is mod_rpaf-0.6.tar.gz. I found a copy at http://sourceforge.net/projects/lnamp/files/soft/mod_rpaf-0.6.tar.gz/download .

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid restarting varnish by using the following method:
http://technosophos.com/2010/09/09/varnish-reloading-vcl-configuration-files-varnishadm.html (link updated thanks to alvherre)

Comment: This link has died.  The article seems to be here: http://technosophos.com/2010/09/09/varnish-reloading-vcl-configuration-files-varnishadm.html

Comment: @alvherre thanks, updated

Answer (score 0):

I would block it on the varnish side

http://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2011-February/005628.html

It would scale better

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way to avoid restarting varnish?

Comment: is the restart to avoid clearing the in-memory cache?

Comment: yes.. It has painstakingly grown to a point where it actually serves its purpose and I would hate to wait a couple of days of increased load to get all these stuff back into mem. (~1.4 million objects)

Comment: use varnishadm, and do `vcl.load somealias /path/to/vcl`, followed by `vcl.use somealias`